# Can we integrate Flutter to native iOS or native Android?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, native

Can Flutter be integrated to a working native iOS/Android code.

Comment: I haven't done it myself, but it seems you can do it according to this page https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app

Comment: Thank you Abed, will try the code and update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate Flutter with native iOS or Android code. For more information you can check this [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels).